# Set Multiple Value For One Property

Tags: c#, database, winforms, class, properties

I have two class that you can see below:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal SuggestionPrice {get; set;}
    public List<SaleOrder> SaleOrders {get; set;} = new List<SaleOrder>();

}
```

```
public class SaleOrder
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get; set;} = new List<Product>();
}
```

as you can see,this two class have `Many-To-Many` RealationShip to eachother.in `Product class` i have `SuggestionPrice` property that i want save `multiple value` in it and it's difference for each `SaleOrder Class`.

for example,Someone offers $ 1,000 in one **SaleOrder** and someone else offers $ 2,000 in another **SaleOrder** for **same product** and infinitely another suggestions that I want to **save them all in database**.

problem is i don't know how can i do this?how can i know witch `SuggestionPrice` is for witch `SaleOrder Class`?

Answer (score 0):

To save in database You should create a SuggestionPrice table like this:

```
public class SuggestionPrice
{
public int Id {get;set}
public int ProductId {get;set;}
public decimal Price {get;set;}
public Product Product {get;set;}
}
```

and change product class to this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<SuggestionPrice> SuggestionPrices {get; set;}
}
```

to create a one to many relation between Product and SuggestionPrice.